# Load javascript faster in the first load itself

Tags: javascript, php, widget, onload, replacewith

I have a temperature widget from http://www.accuweather.com/en/ae/dubai/323091/weather-forecast/323091 and by default it's showing in the website as "DUBAI, AE" on the widget.

I need to make it "DUBAI, UAE" and for that I used the script

```
$( window ).load(function() {
$('.aw-current-weather-inner h3').replaceWith( "<h3>Dubai, UAE</h3>" );
});
```

But while loading the website, it's taking time to load as DUBAI, UAE. Initially the site loads as DUBAI, AE.

I need to see it as Dubai, UAE in the first load itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.ready`, it will take bit less time as compared to `window.load` (it waits to load whole the content like images,videos). In your case, there is only text so you can use document.ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.aw-current-weather-inner h3').replaceWith( "<h3>Dubai, UAE</h3>" );
});
```

Comment: are you think so it is the proper solution before main server response then we have time to display it 
and what if main server is already slow ...????
he is not provide the proper code and Question that's why he got -1... lol ...

Comment: I just present a generalized solution. Sever problem is another issue. But in normal cases if you are not working on image or videos like content, you don't need to use window.load.

Comment: yes agree but i thing there is server problem so that's why i'm asking rather then document.ready() is good solution for this question.... :)

Comment: @MahaDev The problem still exist :(

Answer (score 0):

You cab use `.ready` event of `jQuery`

```
$(document).ready (function(){
})
```

And even i don't think $(window).unload() will take time, this might been the response issue from the server.

If it'll not work, you can make them hide for initial time and then show on loading on the page using `.hide`() and .`show`()